# HTML element to dynamically pop up specific suggestions for field in form

Tags: python, flask, werkzeug

I'm working on a database tool using python+flask+werkzeug and learning how to use most of it for the first time. For the "Institution" field in the template, as the user starts typing in the name I would like existing options that fit the pattern to pop up in a drop-down, then with an option to add a new one if it's not found in that list.  I've found the `<select>` element, and I can see a way to do it with that.  However, it just has hard-coded in choices with no way to type in, and there may be hundreds of institutions I wouldn't want to put all in here. I don't know the terminology for the element I'm looking for so I don't really know what to google.  Any thoughts?

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block header %}
<h1>{% block title %}Add New Member{% endblock %}</h1>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<form method="post">
  <label for="full_name">Full Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="full_name" id="full_name" value="{{ request.form['full_name'] }}" required>
  <label for="phone_number">Phone #</label>
  <input type="tel" name="phone_number" id="phone_number" value="{{ request.form['phone_number'] }}">
  <label for="email">Email</label>
  <input type="email" name="email" id="email" value="{{ request.form['email'] }}">
  <label for="institution_name">Institution</label>
  <select id="institution_name" name="institution_name">
    {% for institution in institution %}
    <option value="{{ institution['institution_name'] }}">{{ institution['institution_name'] }}</option>
    {% endfor %}}
    <option value="not_found">Not found. Add new?</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are JavaScript plugins that allow for this, such as [Select2](https://select2.github.io/examples.html), but a simpler option could be to use a `datalist` element for this.

```
<div>
    <datalist id="institution_list">
        {% for institution in institution %}
        <option value="{{ institution['institution_name'] }}">{{ institution['institution_name'] }}</option>
        {% endfor %}}
    </datalist>
    <input  autoComplete="on" list="institution_list"/> 
</div>
```